# Geo node: I want to use the rotation of object info

Tags: geometry-nodes

I created a tooth mesh using a geometry node.
[image]

This was created with the meaning that the teeth can be moved freely by editing the external mesh line.
However, it doesn't rotate as I expected.
This is because the rotation of the plane is not reflected on the teeth.
[image]

I thought about reflecting the rotation of the plane with a geometry node.
However, I extracted only the x-axis of object info's rotate, but the value is 0. What the heck is going on?
[image]

Ideally, when the plane rotates, the teeth also rotate in the same way individually.
You may be wondering why I don't apply a geomtry node and rotate it as a mesh, but I'm sorry, but I want to control this tooth with a mesh line.[image]

[image]

Comment: When I click on the object "Plane", the _Translation_ data says it is located at (0, 0, 0) and rotated (0°, 0°, 0°). And that's the values you get from the _Object Info_ node with the _Location_ and _Rotation_. This is object information, how you manipulate the mesh in _Edit Mode_ is irrelevant for that node (well, not completely - if you instance something on the vertices, their locations will be used). But vertices themselves have no own rotation, only position data relative to the object they belong to.

Comment: I do not understand your problem: when in *Object Mode* I am rotating around X axis the object named "Plane", I can check that the value displayed by the *Viewer* node is no longer 0. Your second picture let me think that you are rotating in *Edit Mode*. But the *Object Info* node output sockets are providing transformations in *Object Mode*. As Gordon explained, rotation in *Edit Mode* is changing vertices, not the global transformations of an object.

Comment: @StefLAncien That's it exactly, as I said his object is not rotated, it's just an edited mesh.

Comment: Thank you, everyone. I understand that object info node is information in object mode, not rotation in edit mode.